# Google play app store optimization tips

Tags: google-play, publishing

I just published my game on google two weeks ago and not getting installs. How can i promote or make it to come in search results or players find my game?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about marketing, not programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not directly about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you instant help i have only keyword suggestions for you. Did you do keyword research before uploading your game? if no then go with it

[Finding The Best Keyword For Your App (ASO)](http://unity3diy.blogspot.com/2014/11/finding-best-keyword-for-your-app-aso.html)

According to **MobileDEVHQ** test, apps with keywords inside title ranked on the average 10.3% greater than those without having a keyword in the title.

Comment: Thanks dear i will try to improve my keywords

Comment: thanks you find my answer helpfull. 
keyword is most importtant factor in any online success.

Comment: keyword stuffing sometimes become dangerous in search results by google.

Comment: @craiglerr you are right google punish you for keyword stuffing and moved your pages or games to last pages..

Answer (score 1):

Unlike Apple store, Google does not have a keyword text field for you to put words that you think it can be important for the players to find your app.

However, Google will user your **words in your app description**. It means that everything you write about your app can be used to generate results in search. Therefore, I personally recommend you to pay more attention to your app description.

On the other hand, your **App Title and Company Name** have high weight in search results as well.

Hope this helps.